# Adding another field into REST API that from another model

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I've created a REST API that populate data from `Model_A`. but now I need to add another data field into the API that coming from another model. How can I add the `parent` field from the `ModelParent` into my API and the `parent` field also has to be associated properly with `Model_A` project for example below is an example I'm trying to do but not working (**NOTE: model.py are not allowed to be altered in anyway**) :

API :

```
class ReportAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        project_data = []
        all_projects = Model_A.objects.all()
        for project in all_projects:
            project_data.append(project)
            project_parent = ModelParent.objects.filter(project=project.id)
            for parent in project_parent:
                project_data.append(parent)
        project_serializer = SerializerA(all_projects, many=True)
        return Response(project_serializer.data)
```

Rest of the required code :

Model :

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=p_type)

class ModelParent(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Model_A', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('ModelParent', on_delete=models.SET(''), related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
```

Serializer :

```
class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = ('id', 'project_name','project_type')
        depth = 1
```

Current output of my API

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "project_name": "Project A",
        "project_type": "advertisement",
    }
]
```

Desired Output :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "project_name": "Project A",
        "project_type": "advertisement",
        "parent_list": [
                        {
                         id : "1",
                         parent : "Parent 1",
                        },
                        {
                         id : "2",
                         parent : "Parent 2",
                        },
                       ]
    }
]
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Corresponding Model would be as follows: :

```
class ModelParent(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Model_A', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('ProjectContent', on_delete=models.SET(''), related_name='project_parent', null=True, blank=True)
```

Serializer would be as follows:

```
class ModelParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = ('id', 'parent')


class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = ('id', 'project_name','project_type', 'parent_list')
        depth = 1

    def get_parent_list(self, obj):
        return ModelParentSerializer(obj.project, many=True).data #project is related name of project field
```

Comment: Hi @Maulik thanks thanks for your input, my apologies i should've mention that I can't tempered with the model in anyway at all. nevertheless i''ll still try to implement your code tqvm